# Can a method parameter contain a reference to other variable instead of containing a value?

Tags: android, kotlin, methods

In the code below, i'd like to generalize it so I instead of `viewBinding.editText.text` and `viewModel.property.price` can use the same method for e.g  `viewBinding.secondEditText.text` and `viewModel.property.income`.

I'm thinking exchanging `viewBinding.editText.text` for a variable defined in the primary constructor, but then I'd need the variable to contain a reference to `viewBinding.editText.text`/`viewBinding.secondEditText.text` etc. instead of containing a value.

Is this possible? I've looked at lengths for this but can't find anything useful.

```
    fun updateProperty() {

        //... other irrelevant code

        if (viewBinding.editText.text.toString() != "") {
            viewModel.property.price = viewBinding.editText.text.toString().toDouble() 
        }

        //... other irrelevant code

    }
```

Comment: Generalizing by passing in references and property references is one way to do it, but maybe inversion of control might be more convenient for your use case? IoC would be convenient when the cases are hard to generalize, when they dont share commonalities.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters into a function, yeah!

This is the easy one:

```
fun updateProperty(editText: EditText) {
    val contents = editText.text.toString()
}
```

simple enough, you just pass in whatever instance of an `EditText` and the function does something with it.

If you're just using objects with setters and getters, you can just define the type you're going to be using and pass them in. Depending on what `viewmodel.property` is, you might be able to pass that in as well, and access `price` and `income` on it. Maybe use an interface or a sealed class if there are other types you want to use - they need some commonality if you're going to be using a generalised function that works with them all.

---

Properties are a bit tricker - assuming `viewmodel.property` contains a `var price: Double`, and you didn't want to pass in `property` itself, just a `Double` that exists somewhere, you can do it like this:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KMutableProperty0

var wow: Double = 1.2

fun main() {
    println(wow)
    setVar(::wow, 6.9)
    println(wow)
}

fun setVar(variable: KMutableProperty0<Double>, value: Double) {
    variable.set(value)
}

>> 1.2
>> 6.9
```

(see [Property references](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#property-references) if you're not familiar with the `::` syntax)

`KMutableProperty0` represents a reference to a mutable property (a `var`) which doesn't have any receivers - just a basic var. And don't worry about the `reflect` import, this is basic reflection stuff like function references, it's part of the base Kotlin install

Comment: Thank you, I haven't tried implementing it yet but I think it will do the trick! Follow-up question though: Say I'd like to "pass in the property itself" (as you wrote) and not the specific double, would the same general solution (but with a bit of tweaking) suffice?

Comment: @zorigo If you mean ``viewmodel.property``, then that's some type of object that has (at least) a ``price`` and an ``income`` field. If it's a class, and you're passing in various instances of that class, then you can just make that class the parameter's type. If there are multiple classes (or anonymous objects) but they all still have a ``price`` and ``income`` field, you can make those fields part of an interface the objects implement, and make that interface the param type.

Comment: @zorigo if you're gonna be passing in arbitrary objects with different fields (so you might be updating ``thing.income``, or you might be updating ``thing.partyLevel``) then your function is going to need some logic to work out which thing you passed in and what to do with it, like in a `when` block. And you're either gonna need to define a type that encompasses all the things you're allowed to pass in, or your logic has to check for the types it does handle and ignore the rest. Of course at this point it isn't very general! The property reference approach doesn't need to know what anything is

Answer (score 0):

Yes, method parameters can also be references to classes or interfaces. And method parameters can also be references to other methods/functions/lambdas.

If you are dealing with cases that are hard to generalize, consider using some kind of inversion of control (function as parameter or lambda).

You add a lambda parameter to your updateProperty function

```
    fun updateProperty(onUpdate: (viewBinding: YourViewBindingType, viewModel: YourViewModelType) -> Unit) {

        //... other irrelevant code

        // here you just call the lambda, with any parameters that might be useful 'on the other side'
        onUpdate(viewBinding, viewModel)

        //... other irrelevant code

    }
```

Elsewhere in code - case 1:

```
updateProperty() { viewBinding, viewModel ->
    if (viewBinding.editText.text.toString() != "") {
        viewModel.property.price = viewBinding.editText.text.toString().toDouble() 
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in code - case 2:

```
updateProperty() { viewBinding, viewModel ->
    if (viewBinding.secondEditText.text.toString() != "") {
        viewModel.property.income = viewBinding.secondEditText.text.toString().toDouble()
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in code - case 3:

```
updateProperty() { viewBinding, viewModel ->
    // I am a totally different case, because I have to update two properties at once!
    viewModel.property.somethingElse1 = viewBinding.thirdEditText.text.toString().toBoolean()
    
    viewModel.property.somethingElse2 = viewBinding.fourthEditText.text
        .toString().replaceAll("[- ]*", "").toInt()
}
```

You could then go even further and define a function for the first 2 cases, since those 2 can be generalized, and then call it inside the lambda (or even pass it as the lambda), which would save you some amount of code, if you call `updateProperty()` in many places in your code or simply define a simple function for each of them, and call that instead, like this

```
fun updatePrice() = updateProperty() { viewBinding, viewModel ->
    if (viewBinding.editText.text.toString() != "") {
        viewModel.property.price = viewBinding.editText.text.toString().toDouble() 
    }
}

fun updateIncome() = updateProperty() { viewBinding, viewModel ->
    if (viewBinding.secondEditText.text.toString() != "") {
        viewModel.property.income = viewBinding.secondEditText.text.toString().toDouble()
    }
}
```

Then elsewhere in code you just call it in a really simple way

```
updatePrice()

updateIncome()
```